# Is it possible to plot really thin lines in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying something like this:

```
kw = dict(linewidth=0.0001)
e = FancyArrowPatch(pos[u],pos[v],
            arrowstyle='-|>',
            color=G[u][v]['color'],
            connectionstyle='arc3,rad=%s'%rad,
            mutation_scale=0.5,
            **kw)
```

but it seems that it is not possible to generate lines thinner than this.

The result is this (this is the screenprint of an eps file):

[image]

I am ploting this in mpl_toolkits.basemap

Comment: What does it look like in the plotting window? I guess this happens because the viewer thickens thin lines. Acrobat reader for example does this as default, but you can turn it off

Comment: At one point one would probably need to ask how does a line look like that is thinner than a pixel on screen? Is it still there? or not? I think most viewer software would decide to still show it.

Comment: Also maybe it's a good idea to plot the lines with some alpha